# Hide with CSS text contained inside <em> tag

Tags: css

I have this:

```
    <li id="row_resource_id">
    <label for="row_resource_id">
    Ressource
    <em>123</em>
    </label>
```

My goal is to hide "123" but I'm unable to find the correct code for that. I tried this without success:

```
    #row_resource_id em[value="123"] {display: none !important;}
```

I suppose is possible to do with JS but I prefer do that with CSS.

Any clue ?

Comment: Is it you goal to hide it because it is 123, or hide all `<em>` in `<label>` in `<li>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#row_resource_id > label > em {
    display:none;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dpMc4/)**

Answer (score 0):

This works in all my "modern" browsers, I have not checked compatibility everywhere tho.

```
 #row_resource_id em {display: none;}
```